# variable updating in console.log but not in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cant figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Im using jquery to update a variable on screen resize. The purpose of the variable is to fix an overshoot on a `scrollTop` function when the CSS hits the media query 768px.

Here is the code I have for the resize function:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches) {
    var scrollovershoot = 40;console.log(scrollovershoot);
  } else {
   var scrollovershoot = 0;console.log(scrollovershoot);
  }
});
```

Now the function above works exactly as it should in the sense that it logs the correct `scrollovershoot` variable when the screen size hits 768 or below ie a value of 40. The variable doesn't seem to update in my other `scrollTop` function though (it doesn't update the `scrollTop` offset). Here is the code for the scrolling function:

```
$(".fixed-navigation-follow li a, .see-next a, .more-info-cta, .flipper-container a, #main-atf-cta").click(function (){
    var scrollmeto = $(this).attr("href");
 $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(scrollmeto).offset().top - scrollovershoot
 }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

When I resize the screen I get the automatic console logging from my first function displaying the correct value however when I stop resizing and just type `console.log(scrollovershoot);` in the console I get the `scrollovershoot` is not defined message. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scrollovershoot` needs to be a global variable. You are defining it at function level.

Remove the keyword `var` when you are changing it to prevent it to be defined at your function scope, and define it above your snippet to make it global.

Or to be safer, you can make it global by assigning it to `window` which is a global object.

```
window.scrollovershoot = 0;
$(window).resize(function(){
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches) {
      window.scrollovershoot = 40;console.log(window.scrollovershoot);
    } else {
      window.scrollovershoot = 0;console.log(window.scrollovershoot);
    }
});
```

And in your jQuery:

```
$(".fixed-navigation-follow li a, .see-next a, .more-info-cta, .flipper-container a, #main-atf-cta").click(function (){
    var scrollmeto = $(this).attr("href");
 $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(scrollmeto).offset().top - window.scrollovershoot
 }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

When you are using `var`, you are defining a variable at your function's scope. Defining it before your function, makes it global which could be accessed by other functions.

```
// In the browser, `window` is a global object referring to the browser object module.
// More info: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp.

var myGlobalVar;
function f() {
    myGlobalVar = 'something';
    window.myVar = 'something else';
    var myLocalVar = 'some other things';
}
function g() {
    console.log(myGlobalVar); // this works
    console.log(window.myVar); // this also works
    console.log(myLocalVar); // this does NOT work
}

f();
g();
```

Comment: I tested your fix in the console and it still seems to overshoot

Comment: @DannyDyer Can you please create a fiddle or plunker? Maybe the snippet above still is in a function. In that case instead of `scrollovershoot`, try `window.scrollovershoot`. Let me know if this solve you issue so I update the answer.

Comment: But it actually works without declaring the variable outside of the function

Comment: @DannyDyer In your actual project, use `window.scrollovershoot` everywhere instead of `scrollovershoot` and see if it makes any difference. No need to define it.

Comment: do you mean only this line: "    scrollTop: $(scrollmeto).offset().top - window.scrollovershoot"  or everywhere it scrollovershoot appear?

Comment: @DannyDyer Everywhere.

Comment: sorry instructions a bit unclear as im getting syntax errors when adding window. to the start of the scrollovershoot

Comment: Sorry I didnt remove the var = before it! That fixed it, please update the answer and ill mark as correct. Can you briefly explain why this works over my solution? Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to add that you dont need to declare the scrollovershoot before the resize function

Comment: @DannyDyer I'm glad it solved your problem. I updated the answer.

Comment: must say im still a bit confused as to why it worked in the fiddle and not in my page!

Comment: @DannyDyer It is probably because you have other functions wrapped that part of the code. So, defining the variable above the function, still defines the variable in the parent function and not globally. By assigning it to `window` we are making sure it is a global variable as we now `window` is global for sure.